# Dictionary item not returning correct value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm creating a function that returns a proper field name based on a number that is input. The test script is just returning the first key, not the desired value (`1`).

```
def GetFieldName(bldgcode):
    bldgcode = {1: "SFCount", 2: "MFCount", 3: "ComCount", 4: "IndCount", 5: "CityCount", 6: "ShedCount", 7: "SchCount", 8: "ChurCount"}
    for values in bldgcode:
        return values
#test for get field name
print(GetFieldName(8))
```

Running the script is giving me `1` when it should be `ChurCount`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about directly use dict[key] to get name?

```
def GetFieldName(bldgcode):
    code2name = {1: "SFCount", 2: "MFCount", 3: "ComCount", 4: "IndCount", 5: "CityCount", 6: "ShedCount", 7: "SchCount", 8: "ChurCount"}
    return code2name[bldgcode]
#test for get field name
print(GetFieldName(8))
```